# Ruby, Hash, Use Part Of A Composite Key

Tags: ruby, hash

Is there a way to do this? This is called a composite key right?

```
a = { ["key1", "key2"] => "stuff" }
a[["key1",*]]
```

Comment: There's no specific term for this in Ruby since they key of a Hash can be any object, so an array or a string or anything is treated equally.

Answer (score 1):

There is no wildcard interpretation built into `Hash`. You can implement your own with something like:

```
class MyHash < Hash
  def select_composite(key)
    mkeys = matching_keys(key)
    select { |k, _| mkeys.include?(k) }
  end

  private 

  def matching_keys(key)
    keys.select { |hkey| matching_key?(hkey, key) }
  end

  def matching_key?(hkey, key)
    elements = Array(key)
    Array(hkey).each_with_index.select { |helement, i|
      helement == elements[i] || elements[i] == '*'
    }.count == elements.count
  end
end

a = MyHash[{ %w(key1 key2) => "stuff" }]
a.select_composite(%w(key1 *))
```

Comment: The use of `Array(key)` here is rather peculiar. What's the intent? Presuming the arguments and keys are Array is not totally out of line here.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. You would need to linear search of all keys within the hash for the ones that matched your specific conditions.

What you're really after a nested hash:

```
a = {
  key1: {
    key2: "stuff"
  }
}

a[:key1][:key2] # "stuff"
a[:key1] # { key2: "stuff" }
```